# ServletContext.getContextPath() always returns root path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

`servletContext.getContextPath()` always returns `""` when `foo` is expected. Is there a way to find out exactly which context path a controller resides at?

Programmatic spring configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig {

   @Autowired
   private ServletContext servletContext;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       System.out.println(servletContext.getContextPath());
   }
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            some.pkg.WebConfig
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you see what HttpServletRequest.getContextPath() returns to see if it returns "foo" instead of "" ?

Comment: @LeeWallen, I get the feeling that would work and I know for sure the `<%=request.getContextPath()%>` in `jsp` works. But this is a configuration class, there's no request available yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context path is correctly `""`, i.e., the application is deployed in the root url of the application server. What I expected was really the `url-pattern` which is something completely different (and there may be several url-patterns, that's why it cannot be resolved until a request actually occurs).

Although it *might* be possible to retrieve from e.g., [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) I choose the manual approach.